# Profiling cache usage in codeigniter 2.1

Tags: php, profiling, memcached, codeigniter-2

I am using the standard code igniter profiling functionality to view performance breakdown for pages.  I am also using memcache to store the results of some DB queries.  I would like the cache lookups to appear on the profiling summary (so I know I'm not getting all the DB queries on the page and I know the performance of the lookup).  Is there a standard way to do this with CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find anything, so added on github:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/1369